# Put link and session on array

Tags: php, arrays, session

Hello I am doing a query for search using like clause it work and I want to add a link on the result and when I click the link it will display each file. I am using session for the link but when 3 records that display on search which I'm using like example:

> I search grace and it display 3 records that start with Grace

1. 1 - Grace Napoles
2. 2 - Grace Urgel
3. 3 - Grace Smith

> And I want to add link when i click the click it will redirect another page that display there individual record A am using the code below which have the problem display only the last record 
>   3 - Grace Smith will display even i click the 1 or 2 i need your help if i click the 1 or 2 or 3 it display each records thanks

```html
<?php
session_start();
include'database.php';
$ssmain = $_SESSION['sessionsmain'];
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee where E_ID = '$ssmain' || LastName like '%$ssmain' || FirstName like '%$ssmain'";
$no=0;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>


<table class="table  table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
  
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
  
   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$no++;
?>
   <tr>
  
  <td><a href="employeerecord.php"><?php  $_SESSION['ttid'] = $row['E_ID']; echo"{$row['E_ID']}";  ?></a></td>
  
        <td><?php echo"{$row['FirstName']}"; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo"{$row['LastName']}"; ?></td>
  
        </tr>

  <?php
}
}
 else 
{
header('location: error404.php');
}

?>

         </tbody>


    </table>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** You seem susceptible to SQL injection.. Consider [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) in your queries.

Comment: The link is always bringing you to employeerecord.php (see the href property of a). In this way you are not passing any information to that page. maybe You need to change the link to employeerecord.php?id=someid, where someid depends on your loop ($row['E_ID'])

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever going to get the last result (ie: `3 - Grace Smith`) because you're overwriting the `$_SESSION['ttid']` value in each iteration.

You should append a `GET` query string to your link and adjust your code. For example;

```
<td><a href="employeerecord.php?id=<?php echo $row['E_ID']; ?>">
       <?php echo $row['E_ID'];  ?> - <?php echo implode(" ", array($row['FirstName'], $row['LastName'])); ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Now in your query, look for the query string.

```
if( isset($_GET['id']) AND ctype_digit($_GET['id']) ) {
   //Query for the specific E_ID
   $sql = "SELECT `FirstName`,`LastName` FROM employee where E_ID = ?";
   $objGet = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($objGet, 'i', $_GET['id']);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($objGet);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($objGet, $strFirstName, $strLastName);

   echo 'Viewing: '. $strFirstName .' '. $strLastName;
} else {
   //Query all records to show to the user
}
```